# Using Python for a theoretical (conditional) running total

Tags: python

Question - How to replicate the final column 'calculated running op stock' by using the rules. Has to be able to account for multiple products.
(Edited to try and add clarity)

Rules(figures based on example data):

- [row 0] If stock is known- use it(10)
- [row 1] If stock is unknown - use previous weeks opening stock(10) - previous weeks sales(3) + previous weeks production(4) = (11)
- [row 2] If stock is unknown and previous week hasn't completed or happened so sales aren't known - use previous weeks stock(11) - previous weeks forecast(3) + previous weeks production(2) = (10)

Feels like it should be easy, but i'm still new to Python so cant figure it out. Have tried shift(1), but only works for first row without a value. Tried cumsum and notnull with no luck. Happy to be schooled that i should use helper columns or have data running horizontally instead of vertically if this is better practice?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'product':['A','A','A'],
'week':pd.date_range('9/12/2022', periods=3, freq='W'),
'sales':[3,0.5,0],
'forecast':[5,3,7],
'production':[4,2,3],
'opening stock':[10,np.nan,np.nan],
'calculated running op stock': [10,11,10] # This is what i want to calculate based on the criteria above
})
```

Input:

```
  product       week  sales  forecast  production  opening stock
0       A 2022-09-18    3.0         5           4           10.0
1       A 2022-09-25    0.5         3           2            NaN
2       A 2022-10-02    0.0         7           3            NaN
```

Desired Output:

```
  product       week  sales  forecast  production  opening stock  calculated running op stock
0       A 2022-09-18    3.0         5           4           10.0                           10
1       A 2022-09-25    0.5         3           2            NaN                           11
2       A 2022-10-02    0.0         7           3            NaN                            10
```

Comment: I'm just not understanding the question. Perhaps some clarification could help. How are you pulling in your data? Is it a SQL query? is it a self created dataset? Are you trying to sort by the last column?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @JustinEdwards , the data is mainly csv files, but multiple different ones combined to resemble the example. The question is how to create the last column highlighted in red - This is running a theoretical stock position running up to 52 weeks into the future to predict future issues. Hi BeRT2me i will look at improving the example this evening.

Comment: Hi @BeRT2me have added smaller and reproduceable data :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through the rows and assign value based on previous and current row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
'product':['A','A','A'],
'week':pd.date_range('9/12/2022', periods=3, freq='W'),
'sales':[3,0.5,0],
'forecast':[5,3,7],
'production':[4,2,3],
'opening stock':[10,np.nan,np.nan]
})

df["calculated running op stock"] = df['opening stock']
prev_na = False
for idx in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[idx]
    prev_row = df.iloc[idx-1] if idx>0 else None
    if pd.isna(row["calculated running op stock"]): # CASE 0
        if prev_na: # CASE 2
            df.loc[idx, "calculated running op stock"] = prev_row["calculated running op stock"] - prev_row["forecast"] + prev_row["production"]
        else: # CASE 1
            df.loc[idx, "calculated running op stock"] = prev_row["calculated running op stock"] - prev_row["sales"] + prev_row["production"]
        prev_na = True
    else:
        prev_na = False
```

Output:

```
  product       week  sales  forecast  production  opening stock  calculated running op stock 

0       A 2022-09-18    3.0         5           4           10.0                         10.0
1       A 2022-09-25    0.5         3           2            NaN                         11.0
2       A 2022-10-02    0.0         7           3            NaN                         10.0
```

Comment: Hi Arsal, thanks for sharing an answer, it works for the example data which shows 3 scenarios. But if i extend the data doesn't work for all cases 1 & 2.  For example if there is more than 1 week of sales data or if it doesn't align with opening stock figure existing, before switching to forecast. Ideally i think this differential between the Sales and forecast needs to be linked last completed week based on either todays date or having an input date which would get manually changed.